# xfce4-session segfault, suspend and hibernate not working

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, suspend, hibernate, xfce4

I am experiencing some critical bugs during a critical time (finals week) and could really appreciate some life-saving help. I have posted about it at https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10068, but have yet to receive a response from a xfce developer.

[image]

Comment: I just added some important information to the bug report. Please check it out if you can. Photo also available here at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lp4iu&s=5 if more convenient.

Comment: I think this usually happens on machines running 64 bit Ubuntu. An updated package hasn't been released yet, but the necessary [patch](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/commit/?id=ab391138cacc62ab184a338e237c4430356b41f9) is in [git master](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session) for xfce4-session, so you could compile from there. Otherwise, probably best to use another desktop environment if you are doing critical work on your machine.

Comment: Thought I should add that my laptop does suspend when I close the lid.

Comment: There may be two different issues here; the xfce problem (solved by compiling the latest `xfce4-session` from git as my answer showed), and the acpi problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think this usually happens on machines running 64 bit Ubuntu. An updated package hasn't been released yet, but the necessary patch is in [git master](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session) for xfce4-session, so you could compile from there. Otherwise, probably best to use another desktop environment if you are doing critical work on your machine.

**Extra note for other readers**: (If you are using the [xfce 4.10 ppa on 12.04](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10), the fixed package has been released; I'm not sure whether there has been an official update yet for 13.04)

**Compilation from git:**

(For `build-dep` to work, you need to go to software sources and enable source code by checking the box. Then run `sudo apt-get update` and any subsequent `build-dep` commands should work.)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git xfce4-dev-tools libxfce4ui-1-dev libxfce4util-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get build-dep xfce4-session
```

Now, gain the source from git and build (I compared the default options from the package source and they are no significant differences, apart from debug level)

```
git clone git://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session
cd xfce4-session
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo apt-get remove --purge xfce4-session
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=xfce4-session --pkgversion=4.10.1 --provides=xfce4-session
```

Now logout and login to activate the new session.

As this is development code, there might be other issues. So if you have any problems preventing you login at the lightdm screen with this new `xfce4-session`, press ctrl-alt-f1 and login at the console and remove this package and reinstall the normal repository version. Then return to the lightdm screen with alt+f7.

This package may be overwritten (depending on the versions) when the official fix comes out, but that will be fine.

You can of course remove this version and reinstall the package version, although this new version should solve most of the issues.

Comment: Lifesaving information indeed.